# Windows LoadBitmap API (WIN16 Bits)

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, x86

I know how to use the function LoadBitmap(hInstance, idRes) when I have the file put in resource (.rc), but I wanna if it's possible to load a bitmap and get this handle, putting a file, like LoadIcon.

```
LoadIcon, hInstance, 100                                      OK
LoadIcon, hInstance, addr filename                            OK
```

it works very well, but not with LoadBitmap

```
LoadBitmap, hInstance, 200                                    OK
LoadBitmap, hInstance, addr filename                          ERROR
```

So, how can I do to load a bitmap from a user's input, instead resources?

Comment: There are lots of code examples that show how to do this. Websearch will take you there.

Comment: [LoadImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadimagew), for example. Although I don't understand what *"WIN16 Bits"* is supposed to mean.

Comment: @IInspectable I suppose OP is writing a 16 bit Windows program.

Comment: @IInspectable i don't have LoadImage in Windows API for a 16 bit program...

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> LoadIcon, hInstance, addr filename                            OK
> ```

What Windows version or Emulator are you using?

I tried the behavior of `LoadIcon` under Windows 3.1 which is one of the last Windows versions that did not support 32-bit code (and a Watcom compiler tool suite):

Windows 3.1 did not accept a file name as second argument; if the first argument was a valid `hInstance` value, Windows 3.1 always interpreted the second argument as "resource name". Example (`.rc` file):

```
100               ICON   test.ico
"c:\\test.ico"    ICON   example.ico
```

... when I specified "`c:\test.ico`", Windows 3.1 loaded the icon `example.ico`.

I also tried under Linux with WINE 3.6. The result was the same.

So if your Windows version really loads the icon from a file (as you indicate), your Windows version behaves differently than other Windows versions.

Even if there is a possibility to load `.bmp` files using `LoadBitmap`, you have to consider that your program will not work correctly under other Windows versions.

> if it's possible to load a bitmap and get this handle, putting a file, like LoadIcon.

Of course, specifying a name in the `.rc` file would also work with a bitmap:

```
"c:\\test.bmp"  BITMAP  mybitmap.bmp
```

... however, this is probably not what you want.

> So, how can I do to load a bitmap from a user's input, instead resources?

Under Windows 3.1 (and 3.11), there was no function that could load a bitmap from a file directly.

Because later Windows versions supported 32-bit programs, I doubt that Microsoft added new 16-bit functions to newer Windows versions: Using the new function would make a program incompatible to older Windows versions, so the only reason for not using 32-bit code was gone.

The typical approach for loading `.bmp` files under Windows 3.1 was:

- Load the `.bmp` file into memory (Under 16-bit windows, the MS-DOS `int 21h` calls were typically used for file access.)
- At offset 10 (decimal) of the file, there is a 32-bit word containing the offset of the bitmap data ("bitmap bits")
- At offset 14 (decimal), there is a `BITMAPINFO` structure
- Read the size (width and height) of the image from the `BITMAPINFO` structure
- Get some `HDC` (for example by calling `GetDC`)
- Create an "empty" bitmap using `CreateCompatibleBitmap`
- The value returned by `CreateCompatibleBitmap` is a `HBITMAP` handle
- Use `SetDIBits` to write the actual image data to the bitmap
- Release the `HDC` (for example by calling `ReleaseDC`)

Comment: Wow, so thank you! These info will be useful to me! I use Windows 3.11 For Workgroups, installed directly in HD, running MS-DOS 6.22.... And yes, in this version LoadIcon loads a icon from a string (user's input eg)... I will try use offsets like u've said